# NoClassDefinitionFoundError while using JGAP API

Tags: java

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/THashMap

i am using JGAP API for solving Load Distribution problem using Genetic Algorithm.
Problem i am facing right now is not really related to Jgap.
i am trying to create an object of class WeightedRoulleteSelector and i am getting ths exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/trove/THashMap
at org.jgap.impl.WeightedRouletteSelector.<init>(WeightedRouletteSelector.java:48)
    ....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gnu.trove.THashMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Dont have an idea how to overcome this. do i need to add jar file for this??

please help out

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [trove  library](http://findjar.com/jar/trove/trove/1.0.2/trove-1.0.2.jar.html) in your runtime classpath

Comment: added the library..No use!! still having the same issue!!

Comment: downloaded the ZIP, added in the libraries section

Comment: Its not on your classpath at runtime then. and I hope you downloaded .jar and added it

Comment: That jar file contains required class file for sure, So jar file isn't available in classpath when your app is running, What is the nature of your app (java app, java web-app, what?)

Comment: yeah, i checked it out..it has the required class file..
i am making a standalone Java SE application habving swing UI.
i am basically using JGAP API.. the problem arises when i try and create an object of 1 of the classes. looks like JGAP is uning this class although its not getting it.. not sure how to come out of it